# Can I disable the discreet GPU in a hybrid Intel/ATI graphics?

Tags: drivers, graphics, 16.04, radeon, amd-graphics

Using 16.04 LTS at 4.5.2 kernel stable. 
Can I use vgaswitcheroo or something to disable the AMDGPU and the card? It's eating up my battery.
In 14.04 LTS I could use the ATI Catalyst to switch between the power-aving Intel GPU and ATI.

lspci:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)

04:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus XTX [Radeon HD 8890M / R9 M275X/M375X] (rev 81)
```

Comment: I managed to disable it in BIOS, there are ways to do it via a script in lightdm.conf as well. Works fine now.